# Заголовок и описание дела в todo листе выводятся отдельными запросами

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Мне нужно написать todo-лист, чтобы у каждого todo был заголовок(title) и описание дела (about). todo сделан с базой данных на firebase. В отдельных input заполняется заголовок и описание дела. Но когда нажимаю кнопку добавить (Add) выгружается только заголовок(поле в todo для описания дела пустое). При повторном нажатии Add выгружается только описание дела(заголовок остается пустой). И получаются две todo вместо одного полноценного с заголовком и описанием. Прикрепляю ссылку на git-реппозиторий:  https://github.com/Kohlenbaron28/todo

```
//App.js:
import AddToDo from './components/AddToDo';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Title from './components/Title';
import Todo from './components/Todo';
import {
    collection,
    query,
    onSnapshot,
    doc,
    updateDoc,
    deleteDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./firebase";

function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "todos"));
      const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        let todosArray = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          todosArray.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        });
        setTodos(todosArray);
      });
      return () => unsub();
    }, []);
  
    const handleEdit = async (todo, title, about) => {
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "todos", todo.id), { title: title, });
    };
    const toggleComplete = async (todo) => {
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "todos", todo.id), { completed: !todo.completed });
    };
    const handleDelete = async (id) => {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "todos", id));
    };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Title/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <AddToDo/>
      </div>
      <div className='todo_container'>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo
            key={todo.id}
            todo={todo}
            toggleComplete={toggleComplete}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            handleEdit={handleEdit}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//AddToDo.js
import React from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function AddTodo() {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [about, setAbout] = React.useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title !== "") {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), {
        title,
        completed: false,
      });
      setTitle("");
    } else if (about !== "") {
        await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), {
            about,
            completed: false,
          });
          setAbout("");
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input_container">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter todo..."
          value={title}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter about..."
          value={about}
          onChange={(e) => setAbout(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="btn_container">
        <button>Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```
//Todo.js
import React from "react";
import CheckCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";

export default function Todo({ todo, toggleComplete, handleDelete, handleEdit,}) {
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = React.useState(todo.title);
  const [newAbout, setNewAbout] = React.useState(todo.about);

  const handleChange =  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (todo.complete === true) {
      setNewTitle(todo.title);  
      setNewAbout(todo.about);
    } else {
      todo.title = "";
      todo.about = "";
      setNewTitle(e.target.value); 
      setNewAbout(e.target.value);
    }

  };
  return (
    <div className="todo">
      <input
        style={{ textDecoration: todo.completed && "line-through" }}
        type="text"
        value={todo.title === "" ? newTitle : todo.title}
        className="list"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
          <input
        style={{ textDecoration: todo.completed && "line-through" }}
        type="text"
        value={todo.about === "" ? newAbout : todo.about}
        className="list"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <div>
        <button
          className="button-complete"
          onClick={() => toggleComplete(todo)}
        >
          <CheckCircleIcon id="i" />
        </button>
        <button
          className="button-edit"
          onClick={() => handleEdit(todo, newTitle)}
        >
          <EditIcon id="i" />
        </button>
        <button className="button-delete" onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>
          <DeleteIcon id="i" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку, вы отдельно сохраняете заголовок и потом его зануляеете. При повторном нажатии на кнопку, т.к. заголовок пуст, сохраняете тело. Если перед вторым нажатием вы введете что то в заголовок, то сохранится только он. У вас условие так написано, что тело будет сохранено только если заголовок пуст.

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title !== "" || about !== "") {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), {
        title,
        about,
        completed: false,
      });
      setTitle("");
      setAbout("");
    }
```

};